# OSGi to SpringBoot

Tags: osgi

Currently we use OSGi framework for modular application development. But we are now planning to migrate it to springboot . Any relevant articles / tutorials / success stories on this ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Niyas

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific articles regarding this sort of migration but you might like to consider your reasons for the move and then consider the weakenesses and strengths of each technology particularly in the context of your migration and whether you will benefit overall. Do you have any specific reasons for the move?

Comment: Hi Kerry , thanks for the response .. main reasons are : 1) lack of osgified bundles for the third party libraries used 2 ) our applications have many components running in the same osgi container (equinox) .. it is not possible to separate these components to scale horizontally in osgi .. which can be seperated as a microservice in springboot and can be scaled

Answer (score 1):

I don`t think the is a simple migration path. Moving to spring boot will require changes all over the place in your application.

If you are looking into scaling in the form of microservices then this can also be done in OSGi. The [enroute microservice tutorial](https://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial/030-tutorial_microservice.html) shows how to leverage JAX-RS for REST communication and how to package your microservice into a runnable jar. This can then be easily deployed to kubernetes. See [here for the code](https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute/tree/master/examples/microservice).

Comment: Hi Christian, sorry for the belated response and thanks for the info . Will check the tutorial